# Facebook videos & images in App

Tags: android, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Hello want to extend a App which i'm building with facebook.
In this App i was thinking of a special page with only the facebook videos and also a special page which shows only the photos from a specific albums of a facebook company page(public facebook fan page).
Is this possible in a App? I have worked through the facebook sdk's for iOS & Android but these don't mention how you can embed these photos or videos in a App.

Does someone know if this is possible? or has a example or tutorial on this subject?

Many thanks already!

Comment: It's definitely possible to get the album of photos (honestly don't know anything about videos), BUT

The user will have to login with facebook to be able to access anything on facebook at all even if the album is public. Will that be acceptable?

Comment: I know that you need a login but getting the photo from albums does facebook have a json output or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, after authenticating the user the following facebook graph query retrieves the albums of the respective Facebook page (porknbunny being the page name):

```
porknbunny?fields=albums.fields(name, photos.limit(2).fields(name, picture, tags.limit(2)))
```

You can see the results quickly using facebooks graph api explorer

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=porknbunny%3Ffields%3Dalbums.fields(name%2C%20photos.limit(2).fields(name%2C%20picture%2C%20tags.limit(2)))

for video;

```
hilariousvids?fields=videos
```

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=hilariousvids%3Ffields%3Dvideos

Comment: Thanks for the answer do you maybe know how you also can use it for videos?

Comment: yeah same things instead the field is "videos" as opposed to "albums"